# Attributes with colon in DataMapper

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a requirement where I have to do a mapping in dataMapper from a json to SCIM json format which have attributes to be mapped under an Extension schema ("urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"), the DataMapper is throwing an error of unknown attribute when saving the mapping. The attributes under extension schema defined as object, are really needed to be mapped, can anyone suggest a way of acheiving it through DataMapper?